# How do I add a folder with yaml configuration to docker using docker-compose?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a project structure:

```
configs
   -config.yaml
server
...
docker-compose.yaml
```

the docker file is :

```
version: '3.8'

services:
    volumes:
      - /configs:/configs
    postgres:
        image: postgres:12
        restart: always
        ports:
            - '5432:5432'    
        volumes:
            - ./db_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
            - ./server/scripts/init.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/create_tables.sql
        env_file:
            - local.env    
        healthcheck:
            test: [ "CMD", "pg_isready", "-q", "-d", "devdb", "-U","postgres" ]
            timeout: 45s
            interval: 10s
            retries: 10
    app:
        build: 
          context: ./server/app
          dockerfile: Dockerfile
        env_file:
            - local.env
        environment:
            - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
            - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
            - POSTGRES_DB=devdb

volumes:
  configs:
```

The app uses `config.yml` and I'm wondering how to add the configs folder to the container? I tried to do this :

```
volumes:
      - /configs:/configs
```

but it gives me `services.volumes must be a mapping`.

How can this be resolved?

Comment: Services in `docker-compose.yml` file represent the containers. So you should put `volumes` directive inside services.

Comment: As mentioned by Mike Mozhaev, you need to put the "volumes" section where you define the bind inside of your service. You also don't need the bottom "volumes" as these define docker volumes, but you're looking for what's called a "bind mount". The documentation for this is at https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#volumes. Check the short syntax section, it has 5 examples, you're interested in the third one "Path on the host, relative to the Compose file".

Comment: @MikeMozhaev and if another service will also use this config, then you need to put it there too?

Comment: there is a different between bind mounts and named volumes. In your case it would be most easy to use bind mounts meaning you add to each service a volumes list with the entry `- ./path/to/configs:/configs`.

Comment: There are also more complicated ways, in that you create a named volume with bind mount like options. But I would keep this for the future as advanced topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put `volumes` directive inside a service. Probably something like this:

```
    app:
        build: 
          context: ./server/app
          dockerfile: Dockerfile
        env_file:
            - local.env
        environment:
            - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
            - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
            - POSTGRES_DB=devdb
        volumes:
            - ./configs:/configs
```

If multiple containers need it you'll have to repeat it in multiple services.

Comment: thanks . Then I will try to add the file to the services